# Best way to create a bar graph with UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView with several sections.  In each section are rows with various items.  I have a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView for each section and I would like to set the background image for each one to illustrate a particular percentage associated with each section.

I was thinking I could have a simple image with a line and two colors on either side and somehow scale/translate this image so that the line and bar color would fill up the table header from left to right in accord with the percentage value for that section.  This changes so I would need to be able to re-draw it whenever the values change.

I figured that if the image did not scale to fit, but rather the left and right edges were set to bleed instead of tile, then I could just reposition the image in the view.  But I'm not quite sure how to go about that, or even if that's a reasonable thing to do.  Just looking for advice on a good approach for this sort of effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add image to the image view and can show the percentage of the image to the image view as per the percentage you get in that particular sections.Fill your image view with full image and display the percentage accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an image, create a custom `UIView` subclass. Give it a property or two to represent the data. Then implement the `drawRect:` method to draw the graph.

Use this custom view in the table header/footer view instead of an image.

This has the advantage of being more flexible. If you want the graph to be fancier or different, just update the `drawRect:` method as needed.